# aligning a list with a label

Tags: html, css

Here is an example of a label followed by a list which is contained within a span.  The intention is to have the list appear beside the label rather than underneath.  In this example the first list item, "backups", should appear on the same line as the label "path contents:".  How can this be achieved?

```css
    ul
    {
     list-style-type: none;
        border: solid green 1px;
    }

    label
    {
     display: inline-block;
     width: 100px;
        border: solid red 1px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <body>
     <div>  
      <label id="dynamicLbl_pathcontents">path contents:</label>
      <span id="PathContents">
          <ul>
           <li>backups</li>
               <li>FilesAndFolders.php</li>
             </ul>
          </span>
     </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note that the CSS includes borders for the ul and label to improve visibility of those elements in this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block;`, `vertical-align: top;` and `magin: 0` on both `label` and `ul`:

```css
ul {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
     list-style-type: none;
        border: solid green 1px;
        margin: 0;
    }

label {
     display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
     width: 100px;
        border: solid red 1px;
    }
li.file:hover {
     text-decoration: underline;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <body>
     <div>  
      <label id="dynamicLbl_pathcontents">path contents:</label>
      <span id="PathContents">
          <ul>
           <li>backups</li>
               <li>FilesAndFolders.php</li>
             </ul>
          </span>
     </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `vertical-align: top;` for the label?

Comment: vertical-align determines the vertical alignment of inline-block elements.  `top` of `bottom` will align inline-block elements accordingly - so `bottom` would align the bottom borders of these elements. (BTW, the default is `baseline` - alignment along the baseline of the included text)

Answer (score 1):

You can also align using `flex`.

```css
div{
  display:flex;
  align-items: baseline;
}

    ul
    {
     list-style-type: none;
        border: solid green 1px;
    }

    label
    {
     display: inline-block;
     width: 100px;
        border: solid red 1px;
    }

     li.file:hover
    {
     text-decoration: underline;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <body>
     <div>  
      <label id="dynamicLbl_pathcontents">path contents:</label>
      <span id="PathContents">
          <ul>
           <li>backups</li>
               <li>FilesAndFolders.php</li>
             </ul>
          </span>
     </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it without `vertical-align`

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    border: solid green 1px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

span {
    display: inline-block;
}

label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    border: solid red 1px;
    float: left;
}

li.file:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <body>
     <div>  
      <label id="dynamicLbl_pathcontents">path contents:</label>
      <span id="PathContents">
          <ul>
           <li>backups</li>
               <li>FilesAndFolders.php</li>
             </ul>
          </span>
     </div>
    </body>
</html>
```